# 2003 toyota sequioa oxygen sensor upstream color code diagram

Tags: toyota, o2-sensor, sequoia

2003 toyota sequia 4wd engine side the harness connector ripped, i need the color code.Engine side the  wires are green with red stripe, green with white stripe, black, white I dont know how to rewire cables.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There aren't any wires left over from the upstream sensor to match them to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your wiring diagram for all 4 O2 sensors

Green with red stripe is power from fuse box

Green with white stripe is Ground

the other two wires go back to the PCM

[image]